# Grouping Binary Digits in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a binary number, how can I group the same digits in pairs and split the number on single zero?

For example:

```
1100000001111011011 11

[[11, 00, 00, 00], [11, 11], [11], [11, 11]]
```

Comment: In your 2nd example with `000`, how do you know which block the `00` belongs to?

Comment: Is your input a string or a number? Is the desired output a list of strings or a list of numbers?

Comment: @tobias_k 11, 00, 11, 00, 0, 11, 00, 11, 00, 00, 0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 00 - when I have just zero left and it cannot be grouped with next number, then starting new list.

Comment: @mkrieger1 the input is an integer, desired output list of numbers. Sorry, I didn't stated it.

Comment: Then you can't get "00" or "01" as output. Numbers don't have leading zeros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an `iter` of the string to compare the current character to the next one. If they are the same, add them to the current block; if they are different, the first one must be the odd zero, so add twice the one after that to the next block.

```
s = "110011000110011000001111111100"
res = [[]]
it = iter(s)
for c in it:
    if next(it) == c:
        res[-1].append(c+c)
    else:
        res.append([next(it)*2])
```

Or using regular expressions to (a) get blocks of repeated values, (b) split those into chunks:

```
import re
res = [re.findall(r"00|11", b) for b in re.findall(r"(?:00|11)+", s)]
```

Both ways, `res` is `[['11', '00', '11', '00'], ['11', '00', '11', '00', '00'], ['11', '11', '11', '11', '00']]`